# Getting all isoform information and full sequence from Uniprot, Using R

Tags: r

I'm have been having a bit of trouble getting the full isoform sequences from Uniprot accessions. I have used as many packages as I could to find, and used the API. The full sequence exists on their site if you click it yourself, so I am unsure why it would not be available through the API. So I am probably missing something, or, we may have to employ some well written code to put the sequence together, I can find only the bits of the alternative sequence that are different, please see the example below.:

```
library(UniprotR)
accession_numbers <- c('P42226','Q13233','Q495A1','P55285') 
IsoformSeqs <- GetSequences(accession_numbers) 
view(IsoformSeqs) 

#In 55285, for example, we get the "parts" of the alternative sequences in the second row.
#Getting each isoform ID and the full sequence, in two columns, for each accession would be ideal
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting ?if you can show

Comment: For the column I mentioned, VAR_SEQ 628..663; /note=VTVVLFAALRRQRKKEPLIISKEDIRDNIVSYNDEG -> GKLVLPASYLPMVRGSHCYCDTLDLSASPIKAYSLI (in isoform 2); /evidence=ECO:0000303|PubMed:15489334; /id=VSP_000636; VAR_SEQ 664..790; /note=Missing (in isoform 2); /evidence=ECO:0000303|PubMed:15489334; /id=VSP_000637

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in package httr;

```
library(httr)

# UniProt accession numbers for two isoforms of a protein
isoform1 <- "P55285-1"
isoform2 <- "P55285-2"

# UniProt API URLs for the two isoforms
api_url_isoform1 <- paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", isoform1, ".fasta")
api_url_isoform2 <- paste0("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", isoform2, ".fasta")

# Make GET requests to UniProt API for both isoforms
response_isoform1 <- GET(api_url_isoform1)
response_isoform2 <- GET(api_url_isoform2)

# Check if the requests were successful
if (http_status(response_isoform1)$category == "Success" && http_status(response_isoform2)$category == "Success") {
    # Retrieve and print the content for isoform 1
    content_isoform1 <- content(response_isoform1, "text")
    cat("Isoform 1:\n", content_isoform1, "\n")
    
    # Retrieve and print the content for isoform 2
    content_isoform2 <- content(response_isoform2, "text")
    cat("Isoform 2:\n", content_isoform2, "\n")
} else {
    # Print an error message if any request was not successful
    warning("Error in retrieving data from UniProt API.")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).